# How to use HibernateTemplate directly in my testing code

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm trying to make a quick small test on HibernateTemplate. But I always get  exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here.

How can I make the code work? Here're the codes:

The SpringDao.java:

```
package com.question;

import java.util.Iterator;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import com.lavin.test.app.dao.hibernate.a.PersonC;
import com.lavin.test.app.dao.hibernate.a.PersonCId;
import com.lavin.test.app.net.ISimpleServerRunner;

public class SpringDao {

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = null;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory, false);
}


public static ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dao.xml");

private static SpringDao springRunner = (SpringDao) ctx.getBean("springDao");


public static SpringDao getInstance() {
return springRunner;
}

PersonC newPC(String str) {
PersonC p0 = new PersonC();
PersonCId i0 = new PersonCId();
i0.setFirstname(str);
i0.setLastname(str);
p0.setId(i0);
return p0;
}



void test1() {
PersonC p = new PersonC();
PersonCId id = new PersonCId();
id.setFirstname("b");
id.setLastname("b");
p.setId(id);
springRunner.getHibernateTemplate().save(p);
}


public static void main(String[] s) throws Exception {
new SpringDao().test1();
}




/**
 * @return Returns the hibernateTemplate.
 */
public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
return hibernateTemplate;
}



}
```

dao.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                                                                         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize">
        <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property name="minPoolSize">
        <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize">
        <value>30</value>
    </property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">
        <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime">
        <value>1800</value>
    </property>
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <value>classpath:com/question/*.hbm.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                ${hibernate.dialect}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
                true
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">
                ehcache-hibernate.xml
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txProxyTemplate" lazy-init="true"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref local="transactionManager" />
    </property>

    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="test*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="oper*">PROPAGATION_MANDATORY</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="nTest*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="springDaoTarget" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <ref local="springDao" />
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="springDao" class="com.question.SpringDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

and Hibernate mapping files:

```
package com.question;

import java.io.Serializable;
public class PersonCId implements Serializable {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;

public PersonCId() {
}

public PersonCId(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstname = firstName;
    this.lastname = lastName;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

}

package com.question;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PersonC {

private int age;
private PersonCId id;

private Set addresses;

public PersonC() {
}

private Set emailAddresses = new HashSet();

public Set getEmailAddresses() {
    return emailAddresses;
}

public void setEmailAddresses(Set emailAddresses) {
    this.emailAddresses = emailAddresses;
}

private Set events = new HashSet();

// Defensive, convenience methods
protected Set getEvents() {
    return events;
}

protected void setEvents(Set events) {
    this.events = events;
}



/**
 * @return Returns the addresses.
 */
public Set getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}

/**
 * @param p_addresses
 *            The addresses to set.
 */
public void setAddresses(Set p_addresses) {
    addresses = p_addresses;
}

/**
 * @return Returns the age.
 */
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

/**
 * @param p_age
 *            The age to set.
 */
public void setAge(int p_age) {
    age = p_age;
}

/**
 * @return Returns the id.
 */
public PersonCId getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param p_id
 *            The id to set.
 */
public void setId(PersonCId p_id) {
    id = p_id;
}

}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="com.question.PersonC" table="PERSONC">

    <composite-id name="id" class="com.question.PersonCId">
        <key-property name="firstname" type="string">
            <column name="firstname" length="50"/>
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="lastname" type="string">
            <column name="lastname" length="50"/>
        </key-property>            
    </composite-id>

    <property name="age"/>




</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use unwrapped object instead of proxy enriched with transactional behavior. Your initialization should be:

```
private static SpringDao springRunner = (SpringDao) ctx.getBean("springDaoTarget");
```

Alter your names accordingly too. By the way `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` is considered "old style" nowadays. You may consider using `@Transactional` instead.